# Add grunt-notify to M2 Grunt config

Tags: configuration, grunt

How to add `grunt-notify` module to `Magento 2` Grunt config.
Reference: https://github.com/dylang/grunt-notify

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step: 1**

Install grunt-notify

```
npm install grunt-notify --save-dev
```

**Step: 2**

Now load the grunt-notify library by adding below entry in the Gruntfile.js

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-notify');
```

**Additional Configurations**

If you wan to customize the message popup styles and notification timings.

Note: But after adding this overrides only I got notifications in Windows 10.

```
// example configuration for notification hooks
 grunt.initConfig({
    notify_hooks:{
        options:{
            enable:true,
            title: 'Task Completed', 
            max_jshint_notifications:5,
        },
        uncss:{
            options:{                        
                title: 'Task Completeddd', 
                message:"Error occured",
            },
        },
    },             
});
```

**Settings WRT to OS notifications:**

Nothing to install for LINUX and Windows 8.x or Higher. If you are using Mac please read the documentation in [github](https://github.com/dylang/grunt-notify)

**References**

If you yet to configure grunt for Magento there is a [Documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html) on Howto's

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks, I made the same but placed the grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-notify'); before the final brace. Moved to function(task, name) { }), everything working fine now. I have Won 10, too.